# how to begin neural network programming

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

i am quite a novice in the field of neural networks . I have read some theory regarding neural networks. Now i want to do some real coding to realize the neural networks studies in my theory class . Can anyone suggest where to start OR which programming language to use OR any other detail e.g URLS etc.
Thanks a lot for your help

p.s. this post may not be about a real programming situation . but i think this is a great forum to know about all pros and  novice queries

Answer (score 3):

This is a great online wiki: http://grey.colorado.edu/CompCogNeuro/index.php/CCNBook/Main

Theres a great set of example projects that come with it, and it uses the Emergent software which is free and really powerful (grey.colorado.edu/emergent/)

Answer (score 2):

There are various types of Neural Networks and [AI-Junkie](http://www.ai-junkie.com/) has a great introductions on a few of them. They're pretty much the 'hello world' of certain types of neural networks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Stanford course on Machine Learning. The theory is not covered in too much detail, but the coursework examples (e.g. on backpropagation) come with more or less everything you need to get started. The skeleton is provided, you just have to complete the learning bits. The code is in octave, which makes linear algebra really easy.

Answer (score 0):

Use the programming languages you already know (e.g. Ocaml, Haskell, C++, Java ...).

Use or hack or study or improve existing free software libraries for neural networks.